# getting images from folder using php and adding it to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jpeg

lets say I have a folder named "fruits" and inside that folder I have three folders named "apple", "grape", and "banana" and inside each of those I have a jpg of the fruit (apple.jpg, etc). In this situation the folder "fruits" is stored on a server: jackfruits.com/weirdfood/fruits/

how would I go about creating an XML that has a format

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <fruit>grape</fruit>
    <fruit>banana</fruit>
</fruits>
```

and grabbing each of the jpgs then requesting that info in javascript and putting it in an html?
like if I wanted to put them in an html so that the resulting page would look something like:

banana

*PICTURE OF BANANA*

```
<?php
$url = "jackfruits.com/weirdfood/fruits/";

outputXml($url);

function outputXml($url) {
    $files = glob($url . "*");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $fruits = $dom->createElement("fruits");
    $dom->appendChild($fruits);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        #need to create new element "fruit" and put file name in text within it
        #then append to fruits
    }
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    print($dom->saveXML());

}

(function() {
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {
    getRequest;
};

function ajax(address, ffunction) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = ffunction;
    request.open("GET", address, true);
    request.send(); 
}

function getRequest(value) {
    ajax("fruits.php?", displayXml); 
}

function displayXml() {
    var xml = this.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("allfruit").innerHTML = xml.querySelector("fruits").textContent;
}
})();
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: @Mike I editted it. That about all I have so far and I don't know how well it works really because I haven't been able to properly make my XML file nor retrieve the jpgs

Answer (score 0):

Note that `getRequest;` isn't calling the function. It should be `getRequest();`.

You could simplify the directory scan with `scandir()`.

```
function outputXml($url) {
    $files = scandir($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $fruits = $dom->createElement("fruits");
    $dom->appendChild($fruits);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file!='.'&&$file!='..'&&is_dir($file)) {
            $fruit=$dom->createElement("fruit");
            $fruit->nodeValue=$file;
            $fruits->appendChild($fruit);
        }
    }
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    print($dom->saveXML());
}
```

Not tested. Of course assuming that you are sure of your directory structure: jackfruits.com/weirdfood/fruits/***x***/***x***.jpg. You will have to change the code a little bit if there are other files or you'll have to use recursion to walk the subdirectories if there are more levels.

Then, when you do

`document.getElementById("allfruit").innerHTML=xml.querySelector("fruits").textContent`

You're showing **the xml** code inside the `#allfuit` div... You'll have to parse it and generate the html!

...Or simply return the html from php:

```
function outputXml($url) {
        $files = scandir($url);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if($file!='.'&&$file!='..'&&is_dir($file)) {
                echo '<div>'.$fruit.'<br><img src="weirdfood/fruits/'.$fruit.'/'.$fruit.'.jpg"></div>';
            }
        }
    }
```